# How can I send file from a remote AWS S3 to Other Server Using AXIOS in NODE JS

Tags: node.js, api, axios

Hello I am implementing an API endpoint where I can send a file coming from aws S3. What I have done is I get the file in from my s3 bucket

```
let file_data = await S3.getObject(params).promise();
let buf = Buffer.from(file_data.Body);

const file = buf.toString("base64");
```

Now I want to send the file to other API for verification purposes. I tried something like this but doesn't seems to work

```
var data = new FormData();

const data_file = fs.createReadStream(fs.createWriteStream(file));
data.append("document", data_file);

var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: `${process.env.URL}/verify_file`,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        ...data.getHeaders(),
    },
    data: data,
};

try {
    const res = await axios(config);
    console.log(res.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("sendPassport", error);
}
```

Comment: What was the error? Are you meant to be sending the base64 encoded data to the verify service or the original file?

Comment: Hello @Matt I want to send a file base on the buffer. How to convert that buffer into a file an send it to the API?

Comment: `data.append("document", file_data.Body)`

Comment: @Matt I tried that but I get an error [ { error: { type: 'IntegrationError', code: 'media.notFound' } } ].

Comment: The verification api also needs a filename. So my solution below will work in my case

Comment: I think axios needs to use `data: data.getBuffer()` as well

Comment: and `data.append("document", file_data.Body, { filename: file_data.filename })` then

Comment: Thanks @Matt I will try that. But my solution for now is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution. I create a file from a buffer that I get from AWS S3. Then save  it in my current working directory.

```
    let file_data = await S3.getObject(params).promise();

    const buffer = Buffer.from(file_data.Body, "utf8");
    // Create and download a file
    fs.writeFileSync(
                `${process.cwd()}/public/tmp/${data.filename}`,
                buffer
            );
```

Then I converted the file into stream using `fs.createReadStream()` function then send send the file

```
    var data = new FormData();

    const data_file = fs.createReadStream(`${process.cwd()}/public/tmp/${data.filename}`);

    data.append("document", data_file);

    var config = {
        method: "post",
        url: `${process.env.URL}/verify_file`,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            ...data.getHeaders(),
        },
        data: data,
    };

    try {
        const res = await axios(config);
        console.log(res.data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("sendPassport", error);
    }

    // Delete the file
    fs.unlinkSync(file_path);
```